# Mongodb find(query) returning empty

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Please, what am I doing wrong here? My search/query all returned empty. I have tried two approaches (commented out one of them).

```
app.get('/dashboard', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    //check if i still have logged in user in session
    console.log(req.user._id); //confirmed, I have it

    var owner = req.user._id; //assign user id to var owner

    //create a query
    var query = {createdby: owner};

    //first method using where clause  
    Election.find().where('createdby').equals(owner)
              .exec(function(err, elections) {
                    if (err) { return next(err); }
                    console.log(elections);
                    res.render("dashboard", { elections: elections });
            });

    //second method
    /**Election.find(query)
        .sort({ createdAt: "descending" })
        .exec(function(err, elections) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }

                console.log(elections);
                res.render("dashboard", { elections: elections });
            });**/

  //both methods returned empty

});
```

Below is the Model, i can't really see any error from here. Someone should help me out, I ahve been on this for days now and google is not helping.

```
// models/election.js
// load the things we need
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


// define the schema for our election model
var electionSchema = mongoose.Schema({

local            : {
    title: String,
    disc: String,
    startdate: {type: String, required: true},
    enddate: {type: String, required: true},
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now()},
    updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now()},
    createdby: {type: String},
    ballots: { 
        ballot: { type: String }
            }

}

});


  // create the model for elections and expose it to our app
  module.exports = mongoose.model('election', electionSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue. I edited this line:

```js
 //i changed this line
 Elections.find({ createdby: ownerObjectId })
 
 //to this
  Elections.find({ 'local.createdby': ownerObjectId })
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the chainable query builder API, so my response contains a different format. However you could just try the below approach to see if the querybuilder method is the reason or not.

Also I would try to convert the string `owner` to an objectId:

```
var ownerObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id)
Election.find({ createdby: ownerObjectId })
          .exec(function(err, elections) {
                if (err) { return next(err); }
                console.log(elections);
                res.render("dashboard", { elections: elections });
        });
```

Comment: I just tried the above approach, the end product is still the same (returns empty)

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in your callback function? Is err maybe set? If no are you sure that there is an object for the given key with the given value? I don’t see much what could be wrong otherwise

Comment: this is a snapshot from the db:                                                   
 [{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5a218b62509c3700158ab800" }, "local" : { "createdby" : "5a218b44509c3700158ab7ff", "enddate" : "2017-12-27T19:07", "startdate" : "2017-12-21T05:06", "disc" : "6rt6r6r", "title" : "yyyyyyyy", "updatedAt" : { "$date" : 1512147753816 }, "createdAt" : { "$date" : 1512147753816 } }, "__v" : 0 }]

Comment: Don't you see the issue yourself then? The shown document does not comply with the schema you've provided in the original post. The `_id` is apparently an object with a `$oid` as property. That's for sure the issue and not really related to all the information you have provided so far :/